# set value is not working

Tags: solidity, payable

i have develop a hotel booking  smartcontract, it checks the vacancy and price for a guest to book the hotel. i have set the amount such way so that it can be change with time, but the set function is not properly working. guests able to book with any value, not with the value i set.

here is the code

```
    pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract HotelRoom {


address payable public owner;
uint256 public amount ;

    enum Statuses { Vacant, Occupied }
    Statuses currentStatus;
    

    event Occupy(address _occupant, uint _value);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        currentStatus = Statuses.Vacant;
        
    }
    
    

    modifier onlyWhileVacant {
        require(currentStatus == Statuses.Vacant, "Currently occupied.");
        _;
    }
    
  function setAmount(uint256 _amount) public returns(uint256){
        amount= _amount;
    }
    
    receive() external payable onlyWhileVacant  {
       require (msg.value >= amount, " not enough eth provided");
        currentStatus = Statuses.Occupied;
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
        emit Occupy(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: are u using remix, or how are you developing the contract?

Comment: yes using remix